# Error 412 - Manage Bot state Data

Tags: c#, botframework

I've been following Bot Framework documentation to store Bot-Data but even after using the code snippet provided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-state) for handling concurrency I still get error 412 in the emulator. Can you please tell me if I'm saving & retrieving the Bot state correctly.

I've tried setting breakpoints when I'm saving the bot state but it doesn't hit either of the catch blocks.

Emulator's screenshot[image]

```
namespace HealthBot
{
    [Serializable]
    [LuisModel("id", "password")]
    public class RootDialog : LuisDialog<object>
    {
        private const string EntityDateTime = "builtin.datetimeV2.date";
        protected override async Task MessageReceived(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> item)
        {
            var message = await item;
            if (message.Text == null)
            {
                await Help(context, item, null);
            } 
            else
            {
                await base.MessageReceived(context, item);
            }
        }


        [LuisIntent("Claims")]
        private async Task Claims(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> activity, LuisResult result)
        {
            StateClient stateClient = context.Activity.GetStateClient();
            BotData userData = stateClient.BotState.GetPrivateConversationData(context.Activity.ChannelId, context.Activity.Conversation.Id ,context.Activity.From.Id);
            bool isVerified = userData.GetProperty<bool>("isVerified");

            if (isVerified)
            {
                string message = "Yes, but please tell me your claim ID";
                var response = context.MakeMessage();
                response.Text = message;
                response.Speak = message;
                response.InputHint = InputHints.ExpectingInput;
                await context.PostAsync(response);
                context.Wait(MessageReceived);
            }
            else
            {
                await StartVerification(context, activity);
            }
        }

        private async Task StartVerification(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> activity)
        {
            string message = "What is your customer ID";
            var response = context.MakeMessage();
            response.Text = message;
            response.Speak = message;
            response.InputHint = InputHints.ExpectingInput;

            await context.PostAsync(response);
            context.Wait(VerifyCustomerId);
        } 

        private async Task VerifyCustomerId(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> activity)
        {
            var message = await activity;
            string customerID = message.Text.Replace(" ", "");
            string responseMessage = $"You provided, {customerID}";

            try
            {
                StateClient stateClient = context.Activity.GetStateClient();
                BotData userData = await stateClient.BotState.GetPrivateConversationDataAsync(context.Activity.ChannelId, context.Activity.Conversation.Id, context.Activity.From.Id, CancellationToken.None);
                userData.SetProperty<bool>("isVerified", true);
                await stateClient.BotState.SetPrivateConversationDataAsync(context.Activity.ChannelId, context.Activity.Conversation.Id, context.Activity.From.Id, userData);
            }
            catch (HttpOperationException err)
            {
                responseMessage = "Oops! something went wrong";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                responseMessage = ex.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                await context.PostAsync(CreateMessageWith(context, responseMessage));
                context.Wait(MessageReceived);
            }
        }

        private IMessageActivity CreateMessageWith(IDialogContext context, string response)
        {
            var reply = context.MakeMessage();
            reply.Text = response;
            reply.Speak = response;
            reply.InputHint = InputHints.ExpectingInput;
            return reply;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if instead of using the Stateclient you use context.PrivateConversationData?

Comment: I haven't tried it but is there a reason why the documentation doesnt work as advertised. But I can sure let you know once I try.

Comment: It is working & I did find your project at Github. Can you please tell me how to handle time out during 3rd party service calls because I have not found any article on it  at BotFramework Documentation.

Comment: Please add another question around the timeout thing. I added the answer for this question. Please accept/upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of a dialog, I would try using `context.PrivateConversationData` instead of the `StateClient`.

You can check the [State](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-State) C# sample to fully understand how this works.

Comment: @user6083088 Inside of a dialog, the state is auto-saved.  If you use the activity's state client inside a dialog, when the dialog's state is auto-saved there is a conflict.